# how to make this segmented custom bar with indicator

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom bar like this

[image]

However those red boxes are actually images ( nicely designed segments) and the arrow is an image indicator to clarify the progress. I am just showing the image above as an illustration.

I know how to do custom progress bar using gredients and colors but in case of something like that with images. How would I do it? Can it be done through xml or should I create custom view and override the ondraw method to do things from scratch? Any design help is appreciated

Thanks